# Diagram of laravel architecture?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can anyone point me to a diagram that shows the relationship between the normal MVC bits and the following:

- middleware
- Guards
- facades
- Contracts

Laravel seems to have so many middlemen and I'm struggling to see the big picture.

**EDIT**

After thinking about Alex's answer (below) I'm thinking that such a diagram *is* possible. Since some of this relates to general OOP principles, I thinking that a UML Sequence Diagram would be the answer.

Comment: may picture in this link help you to understand flow of model view controller(mvc) : https://selftaughtcoders.com/from-idea-to-launch/lesson-17/laravel-5-mvc-application-in-10-minutes/

Comment: Guards : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896130/laravel-what-is-a-guard?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: facades : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223986/what-is-facades-used-in-laravel?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Contracts :https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073024/9501353

Comment: middleware :https://stackoverflow.com/a/43013324/9501353

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As Your question is very broad, I think providing explanation for all in one image would be like having all flavor in single cake. @Alex in above answer, already have covered the explanation precisely. Here is my take :

**MVC** : A design pattern recommends developer to not mix business logic (Model) with representation (View) and with user's requests Hander (Controller).

Points to Remember :

```
MVC stands for Model, View and Controller.
Model is responsible for maintaining application data and business logic.
View is a user interface of the application, which displays the data.
Controller handles user's requests and renders appropriate View with Model data
```

More details : http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/mvc-architecture

Terms: middleware, Guards, facades, Contracts are part of application logic of  Laravel framework for request cycle at different use-cases, to segregate codes in the application to improve maintainability, understand-ability and cohesiveness. Though even a single page script is enough to do the needful job but it will be a headache to maintain.

**middleware** : Laravel way for filtering HTTP requests entering your application. It seats after router  and before controller in the request life cycle.

More info : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

**Guards** : They're the definition of how the system should store and retrieve information about your users while registration and authentication.

More info : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

**facades** : Facades provide a "static" interface to classes that are available in the application's service container.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades

**Contracts** :  For loose coupling and simplicity. Laravel's Contracts are a set of interfaces that define the core services provided by the framework. For example, a Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Queue contract defines the methods needed for queueing jobs, while the Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer contract defines the methods needed for sending e-mail.

More details : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/contracts

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sorry. It is not an answer. But just some opinion.

You are trying to compare "apples" with "oranges".

MVC concept is a concept related specifically or mostly to WEB development.

It recommends developer to not mix content (Model) with  representation (View) and with logic (Controller).

On other hand things you've mentioned: middleware, Guards, facades, Contracts.

They all are mostly about general programming concepts and kind part or an extentions of OOP principles.

Let not talk about your specific terms: `middleware, Guards, facades, Contracts`, but just about OOP.

**Any OOP principle can be applied to any part of MVC.**

We can create Model using OOP (classes, interfaces, etc) or we can do it some procedural way or mix of OOP, procedural and classic spaghetti.

Same about View and Controller. You can use some OOP principles and techniques or you can limit usage of those or ignore them. That is up to developer and/or probably it depends on the project scope and design.

Coming back to your list: middleware, Guards, facades, Contracts. I would say those are just part of a big family of OOP terms and practices existing in modern software development world. I mean unfortunately we can not do any parallels between MVC and some list of OOP practices.

Another idea I would point is that OOP is much more general than MVC, WEB and data-representation-logic kind software.

Let say we need to develop new OS kernel. I would say there is no that much room to apply MVC for such application. But OOP could be still usefull. Same about embedded systems, or some specific software, drivers, servers, etc...

Comment: If you have the time and willingness, the question is more about (I feel) where in request-response flow come in the guards, middlewares; The facades and contracts are a different concept, but a flowchart of the rest would yield the 50 points from me

Comment: Thanks Alex, I think you had me right there:  { You are trying to compare "apples" with "oranges". }

Comment: ...which then has me thinking. If it's a general OOP thing, then UML is the answer. What about a UML Sequence Diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I created a diagram like this because I couldn't find one myself so thought I would share. It's not perfect but highlights the key concepts and how they're used in the rough order.

It's for using Laravel as an API though so doesn't really focus on views and templates etc.

[Laravel API Conceptual Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lKfH.png)