# How to route the user to the client portal using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, session, authentication

I'm trying to route the user to client_portal.php if they go to login.html when already logged in.

- Tried creating a third .php file that included the session info and tested if the login_user was set
- Tried using jQuery "window.location.replace();" to automatically route the user everytime

This is the code from the third PHP file, checkLogin.php

```
include("session.php");

    if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        header("Location: client_portal.php");
        die();
    }
```

This is from sessions.php
-- DB is a placeholder for the actual info (which is private)

```
    $link = mysqli_connect('DB', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB'); //Connect to the database

    session_start();    

    //Preparing the SQL statements
    $stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT username, first_name FROM login WHERE username =?");

    //Binding the SQL statements
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "s", $user_check);

    $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user']; //Checking if the user has a login session active
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);

    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt1); //Get the result

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //Setting the array

    $_SESSION["login_session"] = $row['username']; //Setting a session under the username
    $firstName = $row["first_name"];

    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        header("Location: /login");
        die();
    }
```

Expected: Route the user to the client portal
Actual: Loads the login page as normal

Comment: It should be `header("Location: client_portal.php");` without `:`

Answer (score 0):

You can create [middlewares](https://www.php-middleworld.com/) for the App, like middleware for **login check** or maybe for **permissions**.

Here is Answers about what is middlewares [What is middleware in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013296/what-is-middleware-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

you are wrongly setting the session variable.
Here is the correct way.

```
$_SESSION['login_session'] = $row['username']; //Setting a session under the username
```

Comment: I changed the PHP in checkLogin.php, but still no response when I login and then change back to login.html

Comment: Under the session.php you are wrongly setting the Session variable. I have edited my answer. It should be $_SESSION['login_session'] = $row['username']; //Setting a session under the username

Answer (score 0):

I thought i'd post my answer incase anyone wants to use this for their project: loggedIn.php

```
$link = mysqli_connect('DB', 'DB', 'DB', 'DB'); //Connect to the database

    if (!$link) { 
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    }

    session_start();

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT logged_in FROM login WHERE username=?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $user_check);

    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { //Checking if the session is not set
        $user_check = ""; //Make the $user_check null
    } else { //if
        $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
    }

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $loggedIn = $row["logged_in"];
```

The main login page:

```
    include("loggedIn.php");

    if ($loggedIn == 1) {
        header("Location: client_portal.php");
        die();
    }
```