# What are exactly Laravel Contracts?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel & I wanted to know something about it's feature that calls `Contracts`.
(If my question not in place, let me know why, and don't just downvote it).
So from what I red in Laravel Documentation and say on Laracasts videos, I understood that contracts they are only interfaces for class implementation.
So what it's good for? That if I or someone else will implement those interfaces will all need to go by the interface and then I dont need to change my code at all?
Is that the reason why Laravel uses it's implementation as a contracts ?
Also I wanted to know, to achive the implementation I must bind the implementation to a contract?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a Contract in Laravel and an Interface in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072046/whats-the-difference-between-a-contract-in-laravel-and-an-interface-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I think your understanding is mostly correct. I will try to explain with an example. Let's say you have a `PackageDeliveryServiceContract` that has some methods like `trackPackage`, `getShippingCost`.

You create a `FedexDeliveryService` to adhere to the contract and implement those methods.

In your controller, you can just inject `PackageDeliveryServiceContract` and start using it right away. (are you familiar with laravel's dependency injection?).

Let's say later you decide you no longer want to ship with Fedex and use UPS instead. Then you can create `UPSDeliveryService` that also adheres to that contract.

Now, all you need to do is change your binding from `FedexDeliveryService` to `UPSDeliveryService` and you don't need to make any changes to your controller code.

Typically you will create the binding between contract and implementation inside a service provider such as `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`